# Swift App crashes when closed in device/Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

sometimes my app just crashes when i close it by double clicking the home button then dragging up to completely terminate the app.

I get the simple green "(lldb)" error from xcode.

Has anyone else been having this / what could be the reason behind it?

Answers appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are killing the app, it isn't crashing. Xcode doesn't know why it terminated. You just shouldn't do that when connected to Xcode...

Comment: @zouvv to elaborate slightly, just click the square stop button to stop your simulator.

Comment: I did it several times in order to restart the app completely. Can you explain the reason behind your advice. Does it harm the app somehow?

Comment: No harm, all Xcode knows is that it didn't tell the app to quit and the app is no longer running, so it thinks it crashed.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just wonder why we shouldn't do. But if it doesn't cause harm, thats okay thanks

Comment: @KutayDemireren there is no reason not to, unless the look of a crash stresses you out, it just makes Xcode think it crashed.

Comment: @Wain ok, so it's basically not an error it's just Xcode wondering why the app suddenly closed. right?

Comment: Correct. It.s easier to just stop Xcode usually, command + period or the stop button, or just command + R to re-run. There are other ways in which the app is killed too, like changing privacy permissions while it's running, also not a true crash.